# How to mark all the outliers in a dataframe when there are around 1/3 missing values?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, outliers

Suppose there is a dataframe with 10000 samples and 4 features and the features are not guaranteed to be independent

```
np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.randn(10000, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[f'Feature_{i+1}' for i in range(4)])

missing_rows = np.random.choice(10000, 3000, replace=False)
for row in missing_rows:
    df.iloc[row, np.random.choice(4)] = np.nan
```

I want to find all the outliers in this dataframe, also I want to mark all these outliers and those NAs with different color or font in the original dataframe. Below is my attempt, and I am trying to use Isolation Forest but I don't know how to do it. Any hint or help would be great, thanks

```
def IQR(series):
    Q1 = series.quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = series.quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1

    LB = Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
    UB = Q3 + 1.5 * IQR

    return ((series < LB) | (series > UB) | (series.isnull()))

for col in data.columns:
    data[f'abnormal {col}'] = IQR(data[col])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example below colours NaNs in, and computes an outlier statistic per column:

[image]

`IsolationForest` doesn't seem to support NaNs, so you must impute them or drop them. Rather than using `IsolationForest`, I've used an IQR function per column.

```py
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randn(10000, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[f'Feature_{i+1}' for i in range(4)])

missing_rows = np.random.choice(10000, 3000, replace=False)
for row in missing_rows:
    df.iloc[row, np.random.choice(4)] = np.nan

def is_outlier(df):
    q1 = df.quantile(0.25, axis=0)
    q3 = df.quantile(0.75, axis=0)
    iqr = q3 - q1
    lower_thresh = iqr - 1.5 * iqr
    upper_thresh = iqr + 1.5 * iqr
    
    return (df < lower_thresh) | (df > upper_thresh)

df_outliers = is_outlier(df)

def style_outlier(v, props='color:white;background-color:royalblue'):
    return np.where(df_outliers.loc[v.name], props, '')

def style_nan(v, props='color:black;background-color:firebrick'):
    return props if pd.isna(v) else ''

(
    df
    .iloc[::1000] #only show every 1000th row
    .style
    .apply(style_outlier, axis=1)
    # .highlight_null() #pandas in-built nan highlighting
    .applymap(style_nan)
)
```

Comment: Amended to use IQR wrapped in a function.

Answer (score 3):

Use `applymap`:

```
outliers = df.apply(IQR)
def style_outlier(v):
    return outliers.applymap(lambda val: "color:red;" if val else "")

>>> df.style.apply(style_outlier, axis=None)
```

[image]